# which domain name is better and why?

Tags: seo, domains, keywords

I am developing a website which has many poems. The users can read and share poems. Which of the following domain names would be better for seo and why?
sharebestpoems .com
poemsilike .com
ilovepoems .com
bestpoemsonly .com
and which one sounds better to you and easier to remember?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an SEO perspective, I think most any of these will be fine. Increasingly, domain names per se are having less and less impact on search performance, at least with Google. As well, people are probably going to be finding you using a whole wide range of possible search terms. This doesn't feel like a topic or a kind of site where one or a few specific phrases are obvious - e.g., Boston real estate, Dallas remodeler. That means that trying to target any particular search phrase is probably not going to buy you much.

As a result, I would suggest your primary focus for the name should be on meaning / comprehension for the user. As such, the words/concepts 'share' and 'poem' seem most relevant. I generally prefer shorter over longer and things that are super easy to remember.

Of your choices, I would go with either poemsilike.com or ilovepoems.com. I also notice that shareapoem.com is available. and sharepoem.com is also available, but not necessarily an improvement. sharepoems.com is for sale via auction at GoDaddy for perhaps $100 (or whatever you can work out).